# Why does Steam not sell the Mac versions of all games?

Tags: steam, macos

Specifically, there is a Mac version of DragonsAge and of Modern Warfare but none of these are offered on Steam.

Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What games are sold on the Steam Store is entirely up to the publisher. If there's a Mac version but it isn't on Steam yet you could try to contact the publisher (EA) to see if they'll put it up.

The SteamPlay feature is very new right now, you'll just have to wait a bit for it.

There is also the issue that Mac versions are usually ported by other companies, so they're depending on sales for that version too. Steam makes it impossible to sell Mac and Windows versions of games separately, so a publisher has to think if it's worth it to sell two full-priced versions of the game for the price of one.

**UPDATE**: Plants vs. Zombies is now available as a [SteamPlay game](http://store.steampowered.com/app/3590/).

Comment: Steam could also refuse to publish a Mac version of a game as well, I would think.  I wonder how much quality control they do.

Answer (score 7):

Just speculating here, but there might be changes that need to be made to a game to get it to work with Steam. This won't be true of all games so we need to look elsewhere.

As Valve have only just released Steam for the Mac the game makers could be waiting to see if it takes off on the Mac and how much demand there is before committing resources to existing games. Even if there's no coding changes there will be things that need to be done and there is the opportunity cost of not doing the other things those people could be working on.

The bottom line is always profit so they might have decided to concentrate on new games that would give a better return on investment.

Comment: Actually, there's no real need to adapt game for Steam unless they have special integration features, ie they use SteamWorks. For example, there's absolutely no reason Plants vs Zombies can't be released by PopCap as a SteamPlay game as it is now, except for the fact they haven't bothered yet.

Comment: speaking of which, pvz is an excellent game

Comment: @Arda - I was just speculating ;)

Comment: And I'm just doing my part to keep the site accurate. ;-)

Comment: @Arda - OK I'll update the answer.

Comment: Are there any steam games for both mac and pc which DON'T use steamplay?  Just curious.

I guess also the mac version of some games are more expensive because they were ported by other companies, and I don't think the mac and pc versions of games can be sold at different prices on steam (specifically modern warfare 1)

Comment: Mechko, no, because SteamPlay is the only way Mac games come on the Steam market. But yes, you're right, there is that. They're basically selling two products as one.
Also, ChrisF, that's still not true. All they'd have to do is upload the Mac versions, if they've got them ready. It's probably only a money issue.

Answer (score 0):

If nobody minds, I’m going to shamelessly plug a tutorial I wrote for just this a few days ago. [How to play PC Steam games on Mac.](http://flax.ie/how-to-play-pc-steam-games-on-mac-os-x/)

Past that, many EA games that have a Mac version use a Cider wrapper, so technically it’s just the Windows game. They mightn’t distribute these Mac versions because they’re not licensed to by Transgaming (the guys who afaik maintain Cider), because they don’t think it’s good enough quality to release to all their subscribers, not sure. On the other hand, I think EVE Online uses a Cider  wrapper…

Either way. I hope the tutorial helps someone out. :)

Comment: Aye, EVE Online uses Cider.